# Krull dimension of $R[X]/(f(X))$ for $f(X)$ monic

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> How can I prove that the Krull dimension of $R[X]/(f(X))$, for $R$ a finitely generated noetherian integral domain and $f(X)$ monic, is equal to the Krull dimension of $R$?

I don't even know where to start, since even to use Noether normalization I would need $(f(X))$ to be prime, right? Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you mean Krull dimension?

Comment: @arsmath yes. edited.

Comment: Krull's principal ideal theorem.

Comment: Note that $f$ must have positive degree.

Comment: @Slade Can you elaborate on how one can use the Krull's principal ideal theorem?

Comment: @user26857 The dimension of $R[X]$ is one more than the dimension of $R$, and the height of $(f(X))$ is exactly $1$, by Krull, unless $f$ is a unit or zero divisor.

Comment: @Slade I'm afraid I still don't get how these help us to prove that $\dim R[X]/(f)=\dim R$.

Comment: @user26857 The dimension of $S/I$ is exactly the dimension of $S$, minus the height of $I$.

Comment: @Slade I'm pretty sure that you can find counterexamples to the last claim.

Comment: @user26857 Okay, but the important thing here is that every minimal prime over $(f)$ has height exactly $1$, which is the statement of Krull's theorem that I had in mind.

Comment: @Slade I can agree with this, but I didn't find a way to get these together in order to come up with a proof of the OP's claim. This is why I've asked you.

Comment: @user26857 A maximal chain of primes in $R[X]/(f)$ can be extended to a maximal chain of primes in $R[X]$ of length one greater, by Krull.  To see that the dimension can't drop by more than $1$, we can extend primes of $R$ to $R[X]/(f)$ (though this probably doesn't save us much time over your solution).

Comment: @Slade Are you using somewhere that $f$ is monic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to assume $R$ domain or noetherian.
We have that $R\subset R[X]/(f)$ is an integral extension, so $\dim R[X]/(f)=\dim R$. (Of course, we suppose $\deg f\ge 1$.)

Comment: How is it obvious that it is an integral extension?

Comment: @user198182 $R[X]/(f)=R[x]$, where $x$ is the residue class of $X$ modulo $(f)$, and $x$ is integral over $R$.

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you